# getLocation and setInterval

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'd like to create an application, what is showing my current position on a google map in "real time".

Here is the relevant code:

```
    function updatePosition() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var myLatLng = {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude};
            marker.setPosition(myLatLng);
            $('#log').append('<p>new position - lat: ' + position.coords.latitude + ', lng: ' + position.coords.longitude + ' </p>');
        });
    }
    setInterval(updatePosition, 2000);
```

How can I say it... It works. But not as I expected. Instead 2secs, it refreshes my position and write into the log about 5 - 30 secs.

Is it possible to do this position refreshing with google maps, or if not, should I use another map like Leaflet or OpenLayers?

Comment: I don't know if this could help you but you may try to set up the timeout as reported in [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition)

Comment: Somebody hates me :))) My second question in one hour, and 1 downvotes and close flag.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [watchPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition)?

Comment: @karacsi_maci I didn't downvote you. I'm used to upvote instead.

Comment: @gaetanoM I did not sad it was you... Thanks for the upvote.

Comment: @karacsi_maci Did you take a look to my suggestion?

Comment: @gaetanoM Yes, and it works like a charm! Thank you. Why did not you answered? If you make an answer, I will accept it, because you was the fastest.

Comment: @karacsi_maci Thanks so much. Upvote/downvote/accept are not my main objective here. I want to share, improve, help and receive help. Thanks, again, so much. I'm very glad for you.

Comment: thank you for asking for this problem. I also had similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run code like this

```
function updatePosition() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        var myLatLng = {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude};
        console.log(myLatLng);
      setTimeout(updatePosition, 0);
    });
}
updatePosition();
```

You'll see that the getCurrentPosition takes a finite amount of time - in my case, 5 seconds, that's with a ZERO timeout ... so, running it every two seconds like you are is not going to make it update any faster

Answer (score 0):

The delay you are encountering is probably due to the delay to acquire the position from the device.
Moreover, try checking for errors as a second handler to the `getCurrentPosition` function.